# merge content of csv files by ID in php

Tags: php, arrays, csv, merge, array-merge

I want to merge two or more csv files that look like this:

File 1:

```
offer-id    merchant-category
123         TV
456         TV
```

File 2:

```
ArticleID   Price
456         989.99
789         555.55
123         999.99
```

The output should look like this:

```
offer-id     merchant-category   Price
123          TV                  999.99
```

It is possible that the files do not contain the exact amount of lines and the lines are not in the same order

Answer (score 0):

1/ load the first csv files

```
$file1=Array();
if (($fp=fopen("data.csv", "r")) {
  while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
     $file1[$data[0]]=$data[1];
  }
  fclose($fp);
}
```

2/ open the second file and merge

```
$result=Array();
if (($fp=fopen("data2.csv", "r")) {
  while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
     $category=isset($data[0]) ? $file1[$data[0]] : "unknown";
     $result[]=array($data[0], $category, $data[1]);
  }
  fclose($fp);
}
```